# When my AMI instance launches, 99-disable-network-config.cfg is created. What is creating it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer, cloud-init

My workflow:

```
Packer -> Kick off a kickstart build of my system on vCloud
Packer -> Export VM as OVA
Packer -> Upload OVA to s3 bucket in AWS
Packer -> Ask AWS to convert my OVA to AMI
Manual -> Launch AMI instance
```

When I launch my AMI instance, I instantiate `cloud-init` early on, after networking service has started.  But `cloud-init` doesn't configure my interfaces because this file is present:

```
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
```

This file tells `cloud-init` to bypass the network configuration and the end result is that my instance is unreachable.

I know `cloud-init` runs because it sets my hostname in another file that I have defined in my custom distro script.  The host gets its hostname from AWS during boot so I know the NIC is functional!  Also, I can see that it gets an IP via DHCP in the `/var/log/messages`)

Config excerpt:

```
system_info:
   # This will affect which distro class gets used
   distro: cent1
   network:
     renderers: ['cent1']
```

Basically, the `distro` script is run (`cloud-init/cloudinit/distros/cent1.py`) but the `renderers` script isn't (`cloud-init/cloudinit/net/cent1.py`).

I have searched through the `packer` code base and the `cloud-init` code base as well as my own code base and nowhere is the actual creation or moving of such a file present.  The only place the file is mentioned is a comment in the `cloud-init` source.  The following comment is found in `cloudinit/distros/debian.py` (my instance is CentOS but the comment explains what the presence of this file does):

```
 34 # To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
 35 # /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
 36 # network: {config: disabled}
```

When I stop my instance and mount its volume on another system, I can see the `99-disable-network-config.cfg` file is present.  Even more confusing is that the top of the file says:

```
[root@host ~]# cat /root/drop1-3/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
# Automatically generated by the vm import process
 network: {config: disabled}
```

When I do a google search, I see other references to the string `# Automatically generated by the vm import process`.

For example, [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=191279) has such a reference.

Another bit of info.  If I manually remove `99-disable-network-config.cfg` in `cloud-init` `util.py` file just before it checks for the `99-disable-network-config.cfg` file, everything works exactly as it should - networking gets configured and I can SSH to my instance.

I'm not putting the `99-disable-network-config.cfg` file there.  I don't see anything in `packer`'s source suggesting that it's putting that file there.  I don't see anything in `cloud-init`'s source suggesting that it's putting that file there.

So the question is, where is that file coming from?  I already have a work-around but I'd like to understand the root cause.  I have not been able to find the root cause of why that file is present.

(Sorry this is so long-winded but I've been staring at this problems for days and have zero solutions other than the heavy-handed workaround.)

Comment: It's definitely not in Packer at least.

Comment: Yes.  I am confident we can make that definitive conclusion from this :-) (I don't mean to tag it in an "accusing" manner, it's just an integral part of my process and others may experience the same).

Comment: Any finding ? I am also facing same issue